# How to send a follow up email for postdoc position

Tags: postdocs, email

I passed the interview for a postdoc position some weeks ago, and the department asked me for various documents so they could begin the mandatory background/references check. I sent in the files pretty quickly (~2 weeks ago), but did not receive any confirmation that they got my email, or any kind of follow up. My references also did not get a call. I assume the international background check part is what's taking so long, since I am very sure that my documents must have been in order (I was very careful in preparing them).

However, I need to decide between this offer and another one this week, and in order to make this decision, I need to see the details of the actual offer they will have for me. I already negotiated a starting date and some other things with the administration, but I'll need to see the proposed contract to be able to compare to the other one. How do I politely ask for an update without annoying anyone or sounding pushy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want information you need to ask. It isn't being pushy unless you do it constantly/frequently.

Ask for an update. Are there missing documents? Are all necessary sign-offs in place? Is there anything I can help with? When might I expect to see a formal offer?

But, there is little to be gained unless you have other options or need certain information in order to make necessary decisions. If it is nothing more than reassurance you seek, then you can probably wait.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yeah, I wouldn't usually ask just for reassurance, but since my other offer expires at the end of this week, I need some kind of guarantee from them (the lack of a formal offer of course also means that I cannot yet be 100% sure that I can fall back on this job, so there is  a bit too much uncertainty for me right now).

Answer (score 0):

"I need to see the details of the actual offer they will have for me."

No you don't. The contract as a postdoc is almost standard, it is also so short in time (how long do you plan to be a postdoc?) that the average postdoc wage in country X, which can be translated as "enjoying life in country X", will be always enough.

When accepting a postdoc position, think about planning the next step, because it is the most enjoyable moment in a researcher life, but it is also extremely short.

Comment: To be honest, I do, because this is not a standard postdoc offer, and has some conditions I need to see. I do not sign contracts I don’t know, and I do not reject other offers based on what I assume to be true. Weighing one against the other is impossible for me right now.

Comment: Ok, then please consider that it will not be the professor (or your future boss) that will decide on these non-standard conditions, because they are bound by their internal rules as well, so you have not to worry in being pushy, just contact/stalk HR because the issue is in their hands and not in the hands of your future boss.